# Idioms/phrases for "I won't get in the way?"

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

Example:

> "Me and Jake? Don't worry I'm a lesbian. You have [...]."

(Meaning she's not going to get in the way).

I can only thing of *having a clear track*. Not sure if it's common, though, since I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: Why not just say, "Me and Jake? Don't worry; I'm a lesbian. I won't get in your way."?

Comment: "a clear shot".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Right of way*, as in “You've got the right of way”, may work.  From [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/right_of_way#Noun), *right of way* has a sense “The right to proceed first in traffic”.  Such a sentence may be used figuratively to tell someone to go ahead.

Also consider the phrase  *clear sailing*. From [idioms.thefreedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/clear+sailing), *clear sailing* means “a situation where progress is made without any difficulty”.  Your example sentence might be recast as “Don't worry, I'm a lesbian. You'll have clear sailing”.

Comment: Why 'you'll have...' and not 'you have...'

Comment: In this context, “You’ll have...” is slightly less presumptuous than “You have...”.  The first of these is like “If you go ahead, you’ll have...”, and the other like  “You're going ahead.  You do have...”.